# iOS stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is not working in a simple code

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I wrote a piece of code about JS:

```
NSString *function1 = @"function getString(){return \"123\";}";
NSString *str = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function1];
NSLog(@"str: %@", str);
```

but the "str" is not equal to "123", the result was

```
str:
```

Any help is appreciated。

Comment: There is a typo in your JS : "fuction". And even if that is fixed, the JS only defines the function, but never calls it.

Comment: you can understand it this way..a function cannot be called automatically. It has to be called. Suppose a script consists of several functions. You will need to explicitly call the function you need. This code doesn't automatically call the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript code only *defines* the function `getString`, but never *calls*
the function. Therefore the result of evaluating the script is empty.

If you actually call the function in the JavaScript

```
NSString *function1 = @"function getString() {return \"123\";} getString()";
```

you will get the expected result.

Comment: OK! I did it. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

This method mosf often usage for running java scripts based on current page contents.
You can see similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560576/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring)

But I've found example with definition of java script [here](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring)